# Sync methods inside angular chaining promises

Tags: angularjs

I am coding a method which is a composition of multiple promises:

```
function myMethod(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    asyncMethod1(data1).then(function(){
        return asyncMethod2(data2);
    }).then(function(){
        return asyncMethod3(data3)
    }).then(function(){
        deferred.resolve(1);
    }).catch(function(error){
        //TODO
    });

    return deferred.promise;
```

The asyncMethods do work as the following:

```
function asyncMethodn(data){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(data.lenght == 0){
       //Nothing to do. Skip method.
       //deferred.resolve()?
       //return;?
    }

    anotherAsyncMethod(data).then(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    }).catch(function(error){
        deferred.reject();
    });

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to deal with the case when the data lenght in the asyncMethod is 0. In this case the method would be sync instead of async. What happens with the chain of promises? How you guys would handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of consistency always return a promise, as you are doing already in `asyncMethodn`.

The `if` condition should just return `deferred.resolve()` and promise chaining in the calling function would work seamlessly. In such a case (`data.length=0`) the promise would be resolved immediately.

You can also use the resolved value of `asyncMethodn` to decided if further call chaining is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
function asyncMethodn(data){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(data.lenght == 0){
       deferred.resolve();
       return;
    }

    anotherAsyncMethod(data).then(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    }).catch(function(error){
        deferred.reject();
    });

   return deferred.promise;
}
```